Init pnpjs/graph inside a word office addin
We want to read a JSON file from a SharePoint document library to provide our Word add-in with selection data.
We are currently testing the possibility of doing this using the pnpjs framework.
Unfortunately, we are not able to initialize the framework correctly.
Do you have an example code for this?
We are currently trying this:
this.graph = graphfi().using(DefaultInit(), i => (i.on.auth.replace(async (s, c) => {
            const l = await this.authService.getGraphApiToken({
                authority: this.authority
            });
            if (!l) {
                console.error("No token");
            }
            return c.headers = {
                ...c.headers,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${l.accessToken}`
            },
            [s, c]
        }), i));

authService working correct.
But a simple call
public async testTokenValidity() {
        try {
            const result = await this.graph.me();
            console.log("testTokenValidity: ", result);
        } catch (t) {
            console.error("Token is not valid: ", t)
        }
    }

doesn`t work.
I would be thankful for any help
regards
Frank
We have investigated various options

The correct way to initialize the pnpjs graph is to use GraphBrowser() instead DefaultInit().
this.graph = graphfi().using(GraphBrowser(), i => (i.on.auth.replace(async (s, c) => {
        const l = await this.authService.getGraphApiToken({
            authority: this.authority
        });
        if (!l) {
            console.error("No token");
        }
        return c.headers = {
            ...c.headers,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${l.accessToken}`
        },
        [s, c]
    }), i));

